# How can I send a input array to backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a form that we can send an array to backend using input with mapping but I ended up created input name different from useState. Like it send seperate data to backend.

Here is my following code in front end:

```
  const initialFormState = {
    rules: teamData.rules.map((value) => value),
    creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,
  };

const [updateTeamData, setUpdateTeamData] = useState(initialFormState);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEditing(false);

    console.log("updateTeamData", updateTeamData);
    console.log("input", inputs);

    // Send update request
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/teams/team/${teamId}`, updateTeamData);

    // If no validation errors were found
    // Validation errors don't throw errors, it returns an array to display.
    if (res.data.validationErrors === undefined) {
      // Clear any errors
      setErrorsArr([]);
      // Hide the errors component
      setShowErrors(false);
      // Call update profiles on parent
      fetchTeamData();
    } else {
      // Set errors
      setErrorsArr(res.data.validationErrors.errors);
      // Show the errors component
      setShowErrors(true);
    }
  };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {inputs?.map((data, idx) => {
      return (
          <input
            name={teamData.rules[idx]}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder={`Rule ${idx + 1}`}
            defaultValue={teamData.rules[idx]}
          />
      );
    })}
```

When I hit submit and the console log gave me this data:

```
{rules: Array(0), creator: "nh1619917421620", "": "3"}
"": "3"
creator: "nh1619917421620"
rules: []
__proto__: Object
```

and here is my code from backend:

```
exports.updateTeamData = async (req, res) => {
  // Get userId
  const userId = req.session.passport.user.id;
  // Get teamId
  const publicTeamId = req.params.teamId;

  // Fetch private id for team
  const teamId = await getTeamId(publicTeamId);

  // The user making the request
  const userPublicId = req.session.passport.user.publicId;

  // The creator of the team
  const creatorPublicId = req.body.creator;

  // Check who is making the request
  if (userPublicId !== creatorPublicId) {
    res.status(401).json("msg: You cant update a team you did not create");
  }

  const picture = req.body.teamAvatar;
  const rules = req.body.rules;

  const rules = req.body.rules;

  console.log("rules", rules);
  console.log("body", req.body);

  // Updates
  const payload = {
    rules: rules,
    mergedTo: teamId,
  };
}
```

How can I do my form right way?

Comment: you can do `JSON.stringify(rules)` at the frontend and then on backend parse it back by using `JSON.parse(req.body.rules)`

Comment: @imranhaider what should I put in  rules at  `const initialFormState = {
    rules: ... ,
    creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,
  };`

Comment: for initialState just initialize it as const initialFormState = {     rules: [],     creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,   }; and then in request wrap it as I mentioned above

Comment: `    <input
                    name={JSON.stringify(rules)}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    placeholder={`Rule ${idx + 1}`}
                    defaultValue={teamData.rules[idx]}
                    // required
                  />`

Comment: so my input cant add the json string in it @imranhaider

Comment: in initialState do as rules: JSON.stringify(teamData.rules.map((value) => value)),

Comment: how bout the name in input

Comment: please change the name to normal for example <input name='rules[]' />

Comment: What u mean like normal ?

Comment: use a string instead of JS expression. so remove dynamiic name from  <input name={JSON.stringify(rules)} /> and place a string

Comment: it just send me back a string i put on. not an array of it